# How to grant access to multiple schemas in one go in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm very green when it comes to the world of database management in SQL Server.

Below is my SQL code to create a login & user & grant permissions

```
USE TestDb
GO

CREATE LOGIN [TestLogin] 
       WITH PASSWORD = N'123', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [TestDb], 
       CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF
GO

CREATE USER SqlUser FOR LOGIN [TestLogin]

GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: dbo  to SqlUser
```

This runs fine & create user/login. He can access the dbo schema.

But I need to specify multiple schemas in the `SCHEMA` options.

So I tried :

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: [dbo,app]  to SqlUser
```

But I get an error:

> Cannot find the schema 'dbo;app', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.

How can I specify multiple schemas in the above SQL pattern to grant access to the user?

Thanks!

Comment: Quite simply: you **cannot** - you have to do this one schema by the next - you cannot grant permission on *multiple schematas* at the same time

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to run multiple statements:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO SqlUser
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::app TO SqlUser
```

If this is something you do regularly, or several users need these permissions, you'd be better off creating a `ROLE`, and then adding users to that `ROLE`. This will enable you to do it in a single statement, with `ALTER ROLE` instead.

```
CREATE ROLE SqlRole; --Give a better, more appropriate name
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO SqlRole;
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::app TO SqlRole;

GO

ALTER ROLE SqlRole ADD MEMBER SqlUser;
```

Comment: Also, is it possible to assign multiple users to one login. Because when doing so getting the error `Login already has an account under a different user name`

Comment: No, @Kgn-web , A `USER` and `LOGIN` have a one-to-one relationship. But if you're using AD, you could create a `USER`/`LOGIN` for an AD Group, instead of the individual AD User(s). But that's a very different question you're asking there.

Comment: When wrapped the above query, in sp it is throwing the error https://pastebin.pl/view/9257bbfc

Comment: What error, @Kgn-web. I get an SSL certificate error for that site, so I am not reviewing it. That code, on it's own, works, which suggests an implementation error.

Comment: @Laru Added the sp & the error in the post itself. Could you please suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Rather taking the value it taking the names as `@loginName` & `@userName`

Comment: That should be a different question, @Kgn-web , however, the error is clear, you're trying to use variables to replace literals. `CREATE LOGIN [@Login]` will create a `LOGIN` with the name `@Login` **not** one with the *value* of `@Login`. That isn't how SQL works. Ask a new question, as that is a different problem.