# How to pass parameter value to a stored procedure rather than text lietral in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

Taking the next step from the recent post (below)

- [How to grant access to multiple schemas in one go in SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60335349/how-to-grant-access-to-multiple-schemas-in-one-go-in-sql-server/60335449?noredirect=1#comment106730608_60335449)

I created this stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser
    @loginName nvarchar(100),
    @userName nvarchar(100) ,
    @schemaName nvarchar(10)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name] FROM [sys].[database_principals] 
                   WHERE [TYPE] = N'S' AND [name] = @loginName)
    BEGIN
        CREATE LOGIN [@loginName] WITH PASSWORD = N'123', DEFAULT_DATABASE = [test], 
                     CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF, CHECK_POLICY = OFF

        CREATE USER [@userName] FOR login [@loginName]

        GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: [dbo] TO [@userName]
        GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA :: [@schemaName] TO [@userName]
END
```

I'm calling this stored procedure like this:

```
DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[CreateUser]
                        @loginName = N'testlogin1',
                        @userName = N'testUserLogin1',
                        @schemaName = N'itl'

SELECT 'Return Value' = @return_value
```

However, this throws an error:

[image: Error]

Upon debugging I see that its not taking the value of the parameters rather the literal.

How do I pass parameter value here to use the values accordingly to create login, user & access?

Thanks!

Comment: You're using literals, not parameters. `[@loginName]` is a *literal* containing the string `@loginName`. That's equivalent to writing `"@loginName"`, in fact double-quotes is the standard way to quote object names. `CREATE LOGIN` doesn't accept parameters. You can't force it to accept them by quoting the parameter name

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is you're trying to use a variable to replace literal. That isn't how SQL works (it's not a Scripting Language). For example, take the statement below:

```
CREATE USER [@userName] FOR login [@loginName]
```

This will create a `USER` called `@userName` which is linked to the `LOGIN` called `@loginName`, **not** a `USER` with a name of the *value* of `@userName` for the `LOGIN` with the name of the value of `@loginName`.

For things like this, you need to use dynamic SQL and ***safely*** inject your parameters.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.CreateUser @loginName sysname, --Changed data type throughout to correct one for objects
                               @userName sysname,
                               @schemaName sysname
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT [name]
                   FROM [sys].[database_principals]
                   WHERE [type] = N'S'
                     AND [name] = @loginName)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
                @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);

        SET @SQL = N'CREATE LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@loginName) + @CRLF +
                   N'    WITH PASSWORD = N''123'',' + @CRLF + --I HIGHLY recommend a better password choice...
                   N'         DEFAULT_DATABASE = [test],' + @CRLF +
                   N'         CHECK_EXPIRATION = OFF,' + @CRLF +
                   N'         CHECK_POLICY = OFF;' + @CRLF +
                   N'CREATE USER ' + QUOTENAME(@userName) + N' FOR LOGIN ' + QUOTENAME(@loginName) + N';' + @CRLF +
                   N'GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO ' + QUOTENAME(@userName) + N';' + @CRLF +
                   N'GRANT SELECT,' + @CRLF +
                   N'      INSERT,' + @CRLF +
                   N'      UPDATE,' + @CRLF +
                   N'      DELETE' + @CRLF +
                   N'    ON SCHEMA::' + QUOTENAME(@schemaName) + @CRLF +
                   N'    TO ' + QUOTENAME(@userName) + N';';

        --PRINT @SQL; --Your debugging friend

        EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
    END;

END;
```

Comment: Many Thanks @Larnu. you're amazing

Comment: just one thing that didn't understand is `@CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) + NCHAR(10);` What is the use of this?

Comment: It adds line breaks, @Kgn-web . SQL that's all on one line is very hard to understand.  [Why I define my Carriage Returns and Line Breaks as variables in Dynamic SQL](https://wp.larnu.uk/why-i-declare-my-carriage-returns-and-line-breaks-in-dynamic-sql/). The name `@CRLF` is a little bit of a give away; **C**arriage **R**eturn **L**ine **F**eed. :)